# Passing value of wx.Frame class to wx.Dialog class in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to python . I am currently creating a GUI which is having 4 options. It means one question and respective 4 choices. User will select 1 choice and when click on OK, it will show a custom Dialog and tell you whether answer is correct or not

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Frame", size=(3000, 3000))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        #panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,  self.OnMove)
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "What are the values of X", pos=(10, 12))
        #self.posCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", pos=(100, 10))
        self.option1 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Apples", (20,100), (160,-1))
        wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Mango", (20,150), (160,-1))
        wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Banana", (20,200), (160,-1))
        wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, "Orange", (20,250), (160,-1))
        button=wx.Button(panel,label="OK",pos=(800, 400), size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newwindow, button)


    # def OnMove(self, event):
        # pos = event.GetPosition()
        # self.posCtrl.SetValue("%s, %s" % (pos.x, pos.y))


    def newwindow(self, event):
        dia = MyDialog(None, -1, 'buttons')
        dia.ShowModal()
        dia.Destroy()



class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(350,300)
        value = MyFrame.self.option1.GetValue()
        print ("***** Value is" , value)
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

I am getting the error. How to get the value of checkBox which is selected by user and pass the same returned value to Dialog class

Comment: A couple quick notes to get you started: (1) You're missing a closing parenthesis in the line beginning with `wx.Dialog.__init__...` in your `MyDialog` class; (2) `value = MyFrame.self.option1.GetValue()` is no good. You want to get the value of the instantiated class, which is the global variable `frame`. Try `frame.option1.GetValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

First do proper parenting for the `wx.Dialog`:

```
def newwindow(self, event):
    dia = MyDialog(self, -1, 'buttons') # refer to instance of MyFrame parent
```

As soon as you do that, you get the reference to the parent frame in the dialog and it can be used:

```
class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        # ...
        value = parent.option1.GetValue() # parent is instance of MyFrame
        print ("***** Value is" , value)
```

As mentioned by @dpwilson, it is no good to try to access a class (`MyFrame`) instead the instance of the class (`frame`).

I think it is better practice to pass the `MyFrame` instance explicitly ("explicit is better than implicit") to the `wx.Dialog` (e. g. by using `parent`) instead of trying to rely on the global variable `frame`. `frame` will not be present if you import `MyFrame`/`MyDialog` from another module.